# Dificuldade em 1:n

Tags: php, mysql

Ola, estou com grande dificuldade em fazer o relacionamento de uma tabela (`clientes`) e outra (`acompanhamento`).
Vamos lá.

Tenho essas 2 tabelas no meu BD - clientes e acompanhamento. A tabela acompanhamento deve ter os contatos dos vendedores com os nossos clientes, ou seja mais de uma linha por cliente, e é ai q surge o problema, não sei fazer a combinação das minhas tabelas para poder identificar cada contato com seu respectivo cliente via ID do cliente na tabela clientes.

Segue a estrutura das tabelas e o código que uso para ver se algum de vocês consegue me ajudar:

**Tabela acompanhamento**

```
CREATE TABLE pluma156_pena.acompanhamento (
      id_mensagem int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      nome varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      mensagem text NOT NULL,
      data_con date NOT NULL,
      data_ret date NOT NULL,
      id_cliente int(10) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (id_mensagem, id_cliente))
```

**Tabela clientes**

```
CREATE TABLE pluma156_pena.clientes (
    id int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    data_cadastrada date DEFAULT NULL,
    data_nascimento date DEFAULT NULL,
    nome varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    telefone varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
    celular varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
    sexo int(1) DEFAULT 0,
    email varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    senha varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    cep varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
    endereco varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    numero varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
    complemento varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    bairro varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    cidade varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY (id))
```

**Código PHP**

```
<?php       
    session_start(); 
    include("../conexao.php"); 

    if (isset($_SESSION['MSLogin']) and isset($_SESSION['MSSenha']) )
    { }
    else 
    { 
        header("Location: index.php"); 
        exit; 
    }

    $Query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE id = '".$_GET["ID"]."'");
    $sqlmensagem = "select id from clientes where id = '".$_GET["ID"]."'";
    $sql = "select * from acompanhamento where id_cliente =  '".$_GET["ID"]."'"; // estou selecionando tudo o que tem na tabela teste bd
    $limite = mysql_query("$sql") or die(mysql_error());

    //laço para mostrar todos os dados da tabela teste
    while($sql = mysql_fetch_array($limite))
    {              
        $id_mensagem = $sql["id_mensagem"];
        $nome        = $sql["nome"];
        $mensagem    = $sql["mensagem"];
        $data_con    = date('d/m/Y');
        $data_ret    = date('d/m/Y');
        //estou mostrando em tela os dados do bd       
        echo "–Assunto-: $id_mensagem–<br>Nome: $nome<br>Assunto:  $mensagem<br>Na data $data_con e retornar na data $data_ret<br><br>"; 
    }
?>
```

O que ocorre é q o resultado n é filtrado pelo cliente que ja foi pré selecionado, ele exibe todas as entradas da tabela `acompanhamento` não somente as linhas respectivas ao cliente com id (15) por exemplo.

Comment: A coluna `id_cliente` na tabela `acompanhamento` deve ser `int(10)`, que é o mesmo tipo de dado da coluna `id` na tabela `clientes` (sua referência)

Comment: Não entendi o problema, está aparecendo algum erro? Não está funcionando como desejado, no caso, como deveria funcionar?

Comment: guilherme alterei para int(10) mas n resolveu nada :/

Comment: o que ocorre é q o resultado n é filtrado pelo cliente que ja foi pré selecionado, ele exibe todas as entradas da tabela acompanhamento não somente as linhas respectivas ao cliente com id (exemplo)

Comment: Leia [esta resposta aqui do site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join/6448#6448) para entender como funcionam os JOINs.

Comment: Em relação ao tipo de dado no banco, era apenas uma observação. Sobre o problema, ainda não entendi muito bem, pode colocar uma foto de como está a saida e de como deveria ficar?

Answer (score -1):

O primeiro grande erro é que while mais mysql_fetch_array() não faz sentido. Ou você usa

```
while($sql = mysql_fetch($limite))
```

ou usa `mysql_fetch_array()` e executa um loop (`for`) em cima da matriz retornada, porque `mysql_fetch_array()` retorna todas as linhas de uma vez.

Também sugiro dar uma limpada no exemplo, tanto para sua própria clareza quanto para deixar a pergunta menos enrolada. A variável `$sql` ora contém uma string SQL, ora contém o resultado de `mysql_fetch_array()`... as variáveis `$Query` e `$sqlmensagem` não fazem nada...

Vá enxugando o código, faça `echo $sql` antes de chamar `mysql_query()` para ter certeza que a consulta SQL está formatada do jeito que você espera, e que o ID seja realmente o código do cliente.